# Show visualization instead of album art in Totem?

Tags: totem

How can I set Totem to show the visualization instead of the album art when I am playing a sound track?

Comment: How can *I* set Totem to show the album art instead of the visualization when I am playing a sound track?

Comment: @ændrük, Totem will show album art if it is embedded into a song's metadata.  Some songs (like the ones you buy from the Ubuntu One Music Store) should already have embedded cover art.  For other songs, you can add cover art to the metadata using a program like EasyTAG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, when embedded cover art is available, Totem will always use it.  There doesn't seem to be a preference option to force it to use the visualization instead.

This [came up on Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/27043/), and the person who mentioned it was encouraged to open a bug report.  It doesn't look like this ever happened -- at least I couldn't find any mention of the problem in [Totem's bug tracker](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi?product=totem) -- so I'd encourage you to [report it](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=totem).

Comment: Ok, I filed a bug https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=651024